# how does bootstrap navbar jumbotron work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

When I put content in  under navbar, the content starts top of the page and blocked by the navbar. So how does the jumbotron class place the content below it? I can't figure it out by looking in the chrome dev tools (i kno...).

So how does one generally place content under the navbar?

Comment: Did you put `padding-top: 70px` on the `body`? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: Thanks. But the jumbotron displays without this property. Do you know where the css happens for that?

Comment: navbar-fixed does obscure the top content if you don't do padding-top:70px; possible you're looking at nabvar-default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the regular, non-fixed navbar, just put your content below it with no special styling.

But if you're using `navbar-fixed`, you DO have to put `body { padding-top: 70px }` to avoid your content being obscured.

`.jumbotron` has no special styling tho avoid this, although it does have it's own internal padding specific to `.h#` classes which pads them, but the `jumbotron` itself is still overlapped by `navbar-fixed`.

See this:

Static Navbar: http://www.bootply.com/gkCqPq2Cti

Nabar-Fixed-Top: http://www.bootply.com/BsBIXWldc2